# Handle exception in rs client cxf

Tags: spring, rest, jax-rs, cxf-client

I tried to search for this but I could not find a solution anywhere. What I really want to do is that I have a rest service implemented on the cloud (3rd party). From my application I just have a rest client implemented (CXF 2.7.2) which calls this service on the cloud and does some processing before returing the response to the client (primarily native mobile app). So basically it acts as a middleware.
Bascically, I want ot implement a generic exception handling at the middleware (rs-client). 
The service implementation (3rd party) is kind of a black box for me and I have no access to their code. When I play with the service using the client, I somtimes get response 400 with a proper message (I finally get a javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException with a message e.g. the input is not valid; and sometimes in certain cases I get a null as a response.

What I want to do is handle all possible (all that I can think of anyway) such cases of responses / codes and convert them to a custom exception. Alongwith this, I also want to handle other cases like timeout etc and convert these also to a custom exception and return it to let the user do what they want to with this exception. Also, log the error along the way.
I saw at various places maybe to handle it using handlemessage but I am not able to arrive at a full implementation.

Comment: Please add your (not full) implementation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can have multiple ways for writing right answers. But to help you in first step I provide you a partly answer where we can achieve more to get your problem solved. But please provide more information in your question.

---

If I understood your question in a right way you can do the following:

- For the first part of your question:

> What I want to do is handle all possible (all that I can think of anyway) such cases of responses / codes and convert them to a custom exception

If your `response code is not a HTTP 200 status code` you can catch this and throw a custom exception. After your know its not a HTTP 200 status code its your choice how you want to handle the status code. You can:

- just throw a custom exception with a default message or
- you can lookup the status code and throw a custom exception with a
  specific custom message based on the status code.

Simple code snippet:

```
if(yourResponse.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()){
       throw new YourCustomException(yourResponse.getStatus() + " Your message");
   }
```

Your custom Exception Class:

```
public class YourCustomException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5724760031556064083L;

    public YourCustomException(){
        super();
    }

    public YourCustomException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

    public YourCustomException(String message, Throwable cause){
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public YourCustomException(Throwable cause){
        super(cause);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) a try, easy to use and light-weight REST client library which has exactly the error handling capabilities you are looking for.

Here is an example for the error handling with the 1.x version https://gist.github.com/benvium/66bf24e0de80d609dac0

If instead you are stuck with JAX-RS/CXF then you need to get a hold of the response object and do your checks there.
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-Handlingexceptions.1